# Using CSS how best to display name value pairs?

Tags: html, css

Should I still be using tables anyway?

The table code I'd be replacing is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

From what I've been reading I should have something like

```
<label class="name">Name</label><label class="value">Value</value><br />
...
```

Ideas and links to online samples greatly appreciated.  I'm a developer way out of my design depth.

EDIT: My need is to be able to both to display the data to a user and edit the values in a separate (but near identical) form.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of page that is? E.g. is it a form, or do you have data which needs to be displayed in a "table"? ;)

Comment: The main title is misleading, it would be good if someone could edit to reflect the fact that IainMH was talking about the layout of form fields.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think that definition lists are pretty close semantically to name/value pairs.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Value</dd>
</dl>
```

[Definition lists - misused or misunderstood?](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/definition)

Comment: The will indent the value, and make it on a new line

Name
 Value

Comment: That depends on the stylesheet. Take a look at the link in my answer and see for yourself.

Comment: Like Espo said, definition lists can be styled in any way you want. You can easily override the default newline/indentation styling.

Comment: I think your answer would benefit greatly from adding the CSS to make it look like a table.

Answer (score 10):

Horizontal definition lists work pretty well, i.e.

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>ID</dt>
  <dd>25</dd>
  <dt>Username</dt>
  <dd>Bob</dd>
</dl>
```

The `dl-horizontal` class is provided by the Bootstrap CSS framework.

From Bootstrap4:

```html
<dl class="row">
  <dt class="col">ID</dt>
  <dd class="col">25</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="row">
  <dt class="col">Username</dt>
  <dd class="col">Bob</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: This works nicely if you have the bootstrap CSS framework.

Comment: Just an update `dl-horizontal` is dropped in bootstrap 4; but there is an alternative (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#typography)

Comment: Also multiple dl elements are not necessary, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/content/typography/#description-list-alignment for an example.

Answer (score 6):

I think tables are best used for tabular data, which it seems you have there.

If you do not want to use tables, the best thing would be to use definition lists(`<dl> and <dt>`). Here is how to style them to look like your old `<td>` layout.
http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly reasonable to use tables for what seems to be tabular data.

Comment: But it sort of isn't a table.  In ASP.NET webforms, I suppose it could be the difference between GridView and DetailsView.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm writing a form I usually use this:

```
<form ... class="editing">
    <div class="field">
        <label>Label</label>
        <span class="edit"><input type="text" value="Value" ... /></span>
        <span class="view">Value</span>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Then in my css:

```
.editing .view, .viewing .edit { display: none }
.editing .edit, .editing .view { display: inline }
```

Then with a little JavaScript I can swap the class of the form from editing to viewing.

I mention this approach since you wanted to display and edit the data with nearly the same layout and this is a way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Like macbirdie I'd be inclined to mark data like this up as a definition list unless the content of the existing table could be judged to actually *be* tabular content.

I'd avoid using the label tag in the way you propose. Take a look at explanation of the label tag @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label - it's really intended to allow you to focus on its associated control. Also avoid using generic divs and spans as from a semantic point of view they're weak.

If you're display multiple name-value pairs on one screen, but editing only one on an edit screen, I'd use a table on the former screen, and a definition list on the latter.

Answer (score -2):

use the float: property eg:
css:

```css
.left {
  float:left;
  padding-right:20px
}
```

html:

```
<div class="left">
 Name<br/>
 AnotherName
</div>
<div>
 Value<br />
 AnotherValue
</div>
```

Comment: This approach contains poor accessibility as name/values are not together.  Also a problem if word wrapping occurs as names and values will become out of alignment.